# Available space is more than total space on the memory card

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, insufficient-memory

I recently purchased a 16 GB memory card. But my android shows available space is more than Total Space and when I try to install a new app it says insufficient memory.

[image: Screenshot]

Total space: 8GB.
Available space: 13.88
Device: Swipe Elite 2
Android Version: 5.1

What's wrong here?

Comment: First you might wish to take a look at our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) to find out that this error has nothing to do with space on the SD card, but with internal storage only. Unfortunately, your question has no details on that, so please [edit] and add it.

Comment: Android version is lolilop 5.1

device: Swipe Elite 2

Comment: Thanks, I've integrated that with your question. Please also [edit] in the other details (how much internal storage you have altogether, how much is used, how much available).

Answer (score 1):

I spoke to the SanDisk customer care and it seems to be known issue. By using the SD Formatter Tool it's possible to restore full capacity on SDHC/SDXC cards.

The below Help center article has more details on it.

http://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/14827/

Thanks,

Arun

Comment: Thanks for contributing to Android Enthusiasts :) You could improve your answer by citing important steps from the article so your answer won't be useless when the link is dead.